# Error while creating a Managed Package

Tags: apex, managed-package, appexchange, gack

I am trying to generate a Manged package but uploading a new Version is showing me an error message

```
common.exception.SqlDupValOnIndexException: ORA-00001: unique constraint (CORE.AKALL_MANAGED_PACKAGE_MEMBER) violated ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CAMPM", line 1182 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CAMPM", line 1446 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CAMPM", line 1774 ORA-06512: at "HAPPY.CAMPM", line 1965 ORA-06512: at line 1 SQLException while executing plsql statement: {call cAmpm.create_ampm_and_fill_fks_nc(?,?,?)}(00D5g00000BjGBx, 04t5g000000xwBa, false)
```

Any Idea?

Comment: opening a case to Salesforce support should be a good action here

Comment: With very high probability, it is related to the Custom Metadata /dependent packages, but SF case is the only option

Comment: Based on past scenarios the issue is most likely because there is a ListView component in the package that references a custom entity that has been deleted (it is a dangling filter). The Salesforce support team can help you identify the dangling reference to be removed.